# Is there a general coordinate transformation perserving the components of an Euclidean metric?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, systems-of-equations, general-relativity

In the Euclidean space (or Lorentz spacetime, if you are interested in relativity), there is one orthonormal coordinate system $\{x^\mu\}$ such that the distance squared is given by

$ds^2=(dx^1)^2+\cdots+(dx^n)^2$

I want to find a general coordinate transformation $y^\mu=\phi^\mu(x)$ such that the distane is

$ds^2=(dy^1)^2+\cdots+(dy^n)^2$

Being general, I mean $\partial\phi^\mu/\partial x^\nu$ are functions of $x^\mu$.

We know that we can find a particular coordinate transformation to make this happen, that is, rotation. Now, if we want someting more general, I guess the conditions are

$\frac{\partial\phi^\mu}{\partial x^\rho}\frac{\partial\phi^\nu}{\partial x^\sigma}g^{\rho\sigma}=g^{\mu\nu}$

and

$\nabla^2y^\mu=0$

The first shows that we can view $\frac{\partial\phi^\mu}{\partial x^\rho}$ as the $\rho$-th compoent of a vector labeled by $\mu$, and these vectors form an orthonormal basis. We can find infinitely many sets of such kind of orthnormal basis smoothly. But it does not seem to me they definitely correspond to a coordinate transformation probably because of the second condition. However, the second condition does not seem to impose any strong constraints on what kind of orthonormal basis we shall choose.

So I get stuck. Please help me out!

Comment: For n-dimensional Euclidean space you're looking for TxSO(n) and for a Lorentzian one, say $R^{n,1}$ you're looking for SO(n,1) to keep your quadratic form invariant.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious way to think about this is to say that since the metrics are the same, the geodesics are the same (viz. straight lines). Therefore the transformation has to map all straight lines to straight lines. Straight lines are of the form $$l^{\mu}(t) = a^{\mu}t+b^{\mu}$$
where $a^{\mu},b^{\mu}$ are constants, and it is easy to see that the only way to make this work is to take $\phi^{\mu} = R^{\mu}_{\nu}x^{\nu}+A^{\mu}$ with $R$ a constant matrix (i.e. $\phi$ is a linear map). Then your first condition gives that $R$ is a rotation (or a Lorentz transformation in the case of Minkowski space).

Comment: Thanks! Great argument. But I remember the definition of a geodesic depends on that of covariant derivative and a general covariant derivative is not necessarily compatible with the metric. So the geometry is determined by the covariant derivative instead of the metric generally speaking. Then it is not clear to me that how a transformation preserving components of the metric maps curves linear in parameter to new curves also linear in parameter. Sorry, when I call the space Euclidean, I mean the distance squared is given in my first post. I did not mean metric defines the geometry.

Comment: @DrakeMarquis You can define geodesics as the curves that minimise the length integral $\int_a^b \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^{\mu}\dot{x}^{\nu}} \, dt$, which only contains the metric.

Comment: I am wondering if I use a different definition of geodesic, what kind of results we will get. Unless different definitions of geodesic are equivalent, I cannot see your argument is sufficient.

Comment: Well, if we work with geodesics defined in the way I suggested (which is certainly always possible...), there's no problem. :) I'm sure there's another way to approach the problem without using anything else, but I haven't thought of it (yet...).